# How to tell which formatter is being used?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working with some Laravel Blade PHP templates. When I format the document either when saving or when running the "Format Document" command, some formatting happens that I don't like, for some example certain Blade-template-specific commands wrapping to the next line when I don't want them to.

My question is, when you run "Format Document" in VSCode, how can you tell what "formatter" is being used? In this case, is it using an HTML formatter, or a PHP formatter or a Laravel Blade formatter? I would like to know this so that I can figure out how to change how the formatter is doing things if possible.

I have some Laravel snippets extension installed as well as some PHP extensions. Can't tell what formatter is being used though.

Comment: Running into the same issue when doing some React development with TypeScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you determine which formatter is being used for VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640469/how-do-you-determine-which-formatter-is-being-used-for-vs-code)